# How to match against multiple characters in a Rust match expression?

Tags: rust

I would like to match a single character against a range of characters (more than one). I'm currently trying an approach using the `..` operator.

```rust
match input_token {
    'Z'..'a' => { // I want to match any character from 'a' -> 'z' and 'A' -> 'Z' inclusive
        ... run some code
    }
}
```

Is it possible to match against multiple values in a single arm of a Rust match expression/statement?

Comment: For multiple value matching, see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#multiple-patterns). Also consider using a regex, if your use case is very complex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pattern for inclusive ranges is `begin..=end` and you can combine patterns using `|`, therefore you want

```rust
match input_token {
    'A'..='Z' | 'a'..='z' => {
        ... run some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use an `if` pattern to handle more complex cases:

```
match input_token {
    token if token.is_ascii_alphabetic() {
        // ... 
    }
    // ...
}
```